# Github not detecting merged files

Tags: github

We are having several issues with Git on GitHub after implementing a GitOps PR system in our company.

We have a few main branches, linked to a CI/CD system, let's call them `main` and `develop`. These branches are protected, you cannot push directly to them.

We had to merge some hotfixes to main that got it ahead of develop for a few commits and caused merge conflicts.

Now the way we are trying to resolve this is to to create a branch from `develop` and pull from `main`. This results in us fixing those **merge conflicts**, pushing the branch to **origin** and raising a **PR** into `develop`. Once the changes are squashed and merged, we create a **PR** from `develop` to `main`, but the conflicts are still there for some reason.

In addition to that, creating another branch from `develop`, pulling `main` and merging it shows us that there are no changes whatsoever.

We have been trying to solve this without removing protection `develop` to no avail.

In addition to that, GitHub has been inaccurate in terms of commits and files with our branches in our PRs. Commits are either inaccurate our outdated, and changed files show changes that were already in both branches long ago.

I am used to personally using bitbucket as a UI for PRs, why is GitHub acting so weird?

Comment: "We had to merge some hotfixes to main that got it ahead of develop for a few commits and caused merge conflicts." So you forgot to merge those same hot fixes to develop?

Comment: We did that on some instances, and on others we just merged main to develop

Comment: Well, then in that case you are not telling the story with sufficient accuracy and detail. The question just rattles on rather randomly and then says "why is GitHub acting so weird", which is not a valid question. The thing to do is take the time to describe the problem accurately and in detail, and ask a clear specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing problems because you have two long-running branches and you're using squash merges.  The [Git FAQ explains this problem](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#long-running-squash-merge):

> In general, there are a variety of problems that can occur when using squash merges to merge two branches multiple times. These can include seeing extra commits in git log output, with a GUI, or when using the `...` notation to express a range, as well as the possibility of needing to re-resolve conflicts again and again.
>
> When Git does a normal merge between two branches, it considers exactly three points: the two branches and a third commit, called the merge base, which is usually the common ancestor of the commits. The result of the merge is the sum of the changes between the merge base and each head. When you merge two branches with a regular merge commit, this results in a new commit which will end up as a merge base when they’re merged again, because there is now a new common ancestor. Git doesn’t have to consider changes that occurred before the merge base, so you don’t have to re-resolve any conflicts you resolved before.
>
> When you perform a squash merge, a merge commit isn’t created; instead, the changes from one side are applied as a regular commit to the other side. This means that the merge base for these branches won’t have changed, and so when Git goes to perform its next merge, it considers all of the changes that it considered the last time plus the new changes. That means any conflicts may need to be re-resolved. Similarly, anything using the `...` notation in `git diff`, `git log`, or a GUI will result in showing all of the changes since the original merge base.

Note that the last sentence also includes GitHub.  There is no way around this, so when using long-running branches you *must* use a merge commit if you don't want this to happen.